# Regex pattern to match AND OR NOT with values operators - search engine

Tags: regex

im trying to write regex to my custom search engine
my input texts:

```kotlin
val examples = listOf(
    "'value'",
    "NOT 'value'",
    "'value' AND 'value1'",
    "'value' OR 'value1'",
    "'value' AND NOT 'value1'",
    "'value' OR NOT 'value1'",
    "'value' AND 'value1' AND 'value2'",
    "'value' AND 'value1' OR 'value2'",
    "'value' AND 'value1' OR NOT 'value2'",
    "'value' AND NOT 'value1' OR NOT 'value2'",
    "'value' OR 'value1' OR 'value2'",
    "'value' OR 'value1' AND 'value2'",
    "'value' OR 'value1' AND NOT 'value2'",
    "'value' OR NOT 'value1' OR NOT 'value2'",
)
val examplesNotMatched = listOf(
    "value",
    "AND value",
    "OR value",
    "NOT value",
    "'value' 'value2'",
    "'value' OR 'value2' 'value3'",
    "'value' AND 'value2' 'value3'",
    "'value' NOT 'value2' 'value3'",
    "'AND'",
    "'OR'",
    "'NOT'",
    "'testANDtest2'",
    "'testORtest2'",
    "'testNOTtest2'",
    "'ANDtesttest2'",
    "'ORtesttest2'",
    "'NOTtesttest2'",
    "'testtest2OR'",
    "'testtest2AND'",
    "'testtest2NOT'"
)
```

Pattern should match all these cases. I tried something like this:

```kotlin
val pattern = Pattern.compile("('(?:[^']*'\\s*(?:AND|OR|NOT)\\s*)*[^']*')\\s*")
```

but it doesnt work.

could someone help me?

Comment: What's an example of something that doesn't match?

Comment: added examples that doesnt match

Comment: Here you go - https://regex101.com/r/kvwLGf/1: `^(?:NOT\h+)?'(?!(?:AND|OR|NOT)'$|[^']*\B(?:AND|NOT|OR)|[^']*(?:AND|NOT|OR)\B)[^']*'(?:\h+(?:(?:OR|AND)(?: NOT)?|NOT)?\h+'[^']*')*$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://regex101.com/r/d1RUHE/1

```
^(?:(?:NOT )?'(?![^'\n]*(?:AND|OR|NOT))[^'\n]*')(?:(?: AND | OR )(?:(?:NOT )?'(?![^'\n]*(?:AND|OR|NOT))[^'\n]*'))*$
```

```
%0 = ^%p(?:%m%p)*$
%m = (?: AND | OR )
%p = (?:(?:NOT )?%s)
%s = '(?![^'\n]*(?:AND|OR|NOT))[^'\n]*'
```

(uses https://tsplay.dev/dimava-regex101-markup-2 to generate resulting regex)

Comment: I added examplesNotMatched, could you adjust it?

Comment: @J.Doe updated (tho idk if it's correct)

Comment: @J.Doe updated. (I have limitations on `\n` to be able to use multiline regex, you don't need it. You may replace spaces with `\s` if you need.)